# Merging multiple CSV files to one dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have have 26 "CSV" files with file names similar to the below:

```
LA 2016
LA 2017
LA 2019
LA 2020
NY 2016
NY 2017
NY 2019
NY 2020
```

All the files have similar column names. The Column names are :

```
Month   A   B   C   Total
Jan    156  132 968 1256
Feb    863  363 657 1883
Mar    142  437 857 1436
```

I am trying to merge them all on Month. I tried `pd.concat` but for some reason the dataframe is not merging.

I am using the below code:

```
list=[]
city=['LA ','NY ','MA ','TX ']
year=['2016','2017','2018', '2019','2020']

for i in city:
 for j in year:
   list.append(i+j+".csv")

df=pd.concat([pd.read_csv(i) for i in list])
```

Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
from functools import reduce    
list_of_dataframes=[]
for i in list:
    list_od_dataframes.append(pd.read_csv(i))
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='Month'), list_of_dataframes)
```

Comment: TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'str'> was passed I am getting this error

Comment: Strange, can you confirm that 'Monthly' (exactly) column is included in all dataframes?

Comment: is it because of my list: here is my list list= [ 'LA2017.csv', 'LA2018.csv', 'LA2019.csv', 'LA2020.csv', 'NY2016.csv', 'NY2017.csv', 'NY2018.csv', 'NY2019.csv', 'NY2020.csv', 'FL 2016.csv', 'FL 2017.csv', 'FL 2018.csv', 'FL 2019.csv', 'FL 2020.csv', 'TX 2016.csv', 'TX 2017.csv', 'TX 2018.csv', 'TX 2019.csv', 'TX 2020.csv', 'NJ 2016.csv', 'NJ 2017.csv', 'NJ 2018.csv', 'NJ 2019.csv', 'NJ 2020.csv']

Comment: List must include the dataframes. 
I changed the code, please check again.